# How does the chain rule work for functions from vectors to vectors?

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose I have a function:

$$ \vec{s} = \vec{f}\left(\vec{\theta}\right)$$

and a derivative:

$$ \vec{v} = \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{s}}{\mathrm{d} t}$$

How do I apply the chain rule?

For simplicity lets call $\omega = \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{\theta}}{\mathrm{d} t}$

I think the chain rule should be something along the line of:

$$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \nabla_{\theta} \vec{f}\left(\theta\right) $$

but I don't know the exact rule.

I think I may have to use matrices and more complicated derivatives like the Jacobian.

Comment: Gave you an analytic answer down below of how to define and express it. Make sure you ask me anything you may not understand if the answer fits your needs make sure to approve is to that the thread goes down as answered.

Comment: For functions from vectors to vectors the derivative at a point is a matrix (the Jacobian) and the chain rule says that the derivative of a composite is the matrix product of the derivatives of the individual pieces.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually the definition of the gradient that
$$\langle \nabla f(p), X\rangle = df(p) X$$
so
$$\frac{d}{dt}f\circ \theta(t) = df(\theta)\theta^\prime = \langle \nabla f(p), \theta^\prime\rangle$$
where $\theta^\prime=\frac{d}{dt}\theta$.

Comment: What type of product is $\left<u, v\right>$?

Comment: is the product just an alternative notation for the inner product?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus it's the scalar product.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a particular component $v_k$ of the velocity vector $\vec{v}(\vec{\theta})$. Then the chain rule yields

$$\displaystyle v_k = \frac{ds_k}{dt}= \sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial s_k}{\partial \theta_j}\frac{d\theta_j}{dt} =\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial s_k}{\partial \theta_j}\omega_j.$$ If we understand $\nabla_{\vec{\theta}} F=\sum_{j=1}^3 \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta_j}\hat{e}_k,$ the above may be written as $v_k=\nabla_{\vec{\theta}}s_k\cdot \vec{\omega}$ i.e. $\vec{v}=\nabla_{\vec{\theta}}\vec{s}\cdot \vec{\omega}.$ This reflects the fact that the first term is a rank 2 tensor, and so the use of the dot product (instead of the cross product) is warranted in order to obtain a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Ok then, $\theta:R\rightarrow R^n$ and $f:R^n\rightarrow R^p$ so $f\circ \theta:R\rightarrow R^p.$ Then it's true the derivative has to be a vector and it is precisely the vector of $R^p$ that in the $ith$ component has $\nabla F_i(\theta(t))\cdot \theta'(t)$, where the $F_i:R^n\rightarrow R, (i=\overline{1, p})$ are the components of $f$.

Comment: The derivative $\frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{s}}{\mathrm{d} t}$ is a vector and not a scalar so your answer can't be possible.

Comment: Sorry, now it makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: D \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a scalar field defined in an open ball about $a$ and let $x: I \subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n $ be a vector-valued function defined in an open interval about $t_0$. Let $x(t_0) = a$ and $x(I) \subset D$. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and if $x$ is differentiable at $t_0$, then $f(x)$ is differentiable at $t_0$ and its derivative is given by :

$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t_0)) = \nabla f(x(t_0))x'(t_0)$

We can write this formula in scalar form as : $\frac{d}{dt}(f o x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\frac{dx_1}{dt} + ...+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\frac{dx_n}{dt} $.

You can also write that in matrix form and then, recalling the definition of the Jacobian matrix $Df$ the latter can be recognized as :

$\frac{d}{dt}(f(x(t))=Df(x(t))Dx(t)$.

Comment: What is the type of object that $\nabla f\left(x\right)$ is?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus Normally, that stands for the gradient of a function.

Comment: @Scounged Yes but what is the result of the gradient? Is it a vector, matrix or a tensor?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus it should be a normal vector, right? At least that's how I see it after looking at the definition of $f$ in this answer. Such a view makes sense if you look at the line that immediately follows the gradient notation.